# Syntax error in MySQL search which appears correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having a syntax error from a MySQL query which is baffling me a little. As far as I can see online this appears to be the correct way of working things and I'm certain I have the table name and variables correct.

So here is the error I am recieving;

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `date` = ORDER BY 'scriptno' ASC' at line 3`
```

and here is the code that seems to be the problem [but as far as I can see it's not...

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT script FROM `tableoscripts` WHERE `event` = $_GET[$eventq] AND `date` = $_GET[$dateq] ORDER BY 'scriptno' ASC") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

In case you are wondering the previous page is heading to this one using the get method and the details are showing up in the address bar after submission.

Comment: Please don't put values from `$_GET` directly into queries; you're making your script vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Did you define $eventq? Are you sure you don't mean $_GET['eventq']? Also, you should never use user input directly. Use PDO/mysqli. Echo the final query to see what it is.

Comment: when using array values in strings I usually have to put curls around them.... `date = '{$_GET[$dateq]}' order by...`... and you should try putting the whole query in a variable and do a var_dump on it to see what is actually happening to the string before trying to run the query.  make sure that the query is actually what it should be and runs directly in mysql before executing through php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote your values:

```
...WHERE `event` = '$_GET[$eventq]' AND `date` = '$_GET[$dateq]'...
```

Be aware that it is dangerous to use unfiltered user data in queries. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for SQL-injection attack and mitigation information.

Comment: +1 . `ORDER BY 'scriptno' ASC"` -> here `scriptno` doesn't need to be enclosed by single quotes, right?

Comment: @kevin Correct, single quotes aren't helpful. Backticks should encapsulate field names: `ORDER BY \`scriptno\`` to prevent conflicts with MySQL reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET[$dateq]` is empty / undefined therefore your query is broken at the position the error message tells you.

```
AND `date` =   ORDER BY
             ^-- Your variable should bere here.
```

Comment: The error occurs at `'AND `date` = ORDER BY 'scriptno' ASC'`. This means that there is already an error before that.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around your data?

```
$data = mysql_query("
SELECT script 
FROM `tableoscripts` 
WHERE `event` = '$_GET[$eventq]' 
    AND `date` = '$_GET[$dateq]' 
ORDER BY 'scriptno' ASC")
 or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET[$eventq]` and `$_GET[$dateq]`

probably should be

`{$_GET['eventq']}` and `{$_GET['dateq']}`.

**And escape them both first!**

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with "date=$_Get[$dateq]" You may have to convert it to the date format.
In oracle you can use to_date() function. Not sure about the equivalent function in MySql.

Answer (score 0):

If $eventq and $dateq are defined than the following shout work

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT script FROM `tableoscripts` 
        WHERE `event` = '{$_GET[$eventq]}' AND `date` = '{$_GET[$dateq]'}
        ORDER BY 'scriptno' ASC") or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
```